# Best Approach to sync users from Active Directoy into Application

Tags: active-directory

I have a new requirement in the project.

We have an MVC application and now we need to import users from active directory. We are not doing any kind of authentication with AD (I understand the AD should be used for authentication), but just importing user information into our application.

We have multiple client who can configure their respective Active Directory settings.

Whenever there are changes in the AD we need sync back into our application (this is just one way).

Now the question comes, is it a good idea to have a service installed on client end to get the users from AD and send it to our application ??

I know that no client will give the LDAP credentials. But still want to know if this is a good design or not ?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach to me, as far as generating a file with the GUIDs of the LDAP objects and then all the values you care about and then having that CSV (or JSON ,or whatever) sent to a site via HTTPS with a token or username/password or something. Or just a manual upload process option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because searches against Active Directory require CPU and memory
>   resources, searches should be performed in ways that minimize their
>   performance impact on domain controllers. You can use several
>   techniques to reduce the impact of directory searches on domain
>   controllers... [[Source]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755809(v=ws.10).aspx)

In other words, consider a bulk import service in case of regular heavy search operations with hundreds or thousands of objects, wildcard search, nested structures and multiple domains. For example, you could design a MVC controller or batch job that runs every night and imports required data from AD to your database from where the data can be more easily queried and processed. This should drastically increase your performance and reduce the impact on AD. Use the *WhenChanged* attribute to import only updated objects.

On another hand, if your queries to AD are rare, point to a single object (e.g. user attributes, such as name/email/phone) and processed quickly, then an import could be an overkill because the same could be done using direct calls to AD.